# Problema con datagridview al eliminar elemento de lista generica asociada

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente formulario:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al intentar eliminar un presupuesto hago:

```
   public static void eliminarPresupuesto(int idpresupuesto)
    {

        Presupuesto eliminar = listaPresupuestos.Where(x => x.idpresupuesto == idpresupuesto).FirstOrDefault();
        listaPresupuestos.Remove(eliminar);
       
    }
    public void eliminar(int idpresupuesto)
    {
       
        using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(""))
        {
            connection.Open();
            string sql = "DELETE FROM presupuesto WHERE idpresupuesto=" + idpresupuesto;
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
           
        }
        eliminarPresupuesto(idpresupuesto);
    }
```

como veran remuevo el elemento de la lista..para cargar el grid hago:

```
 listaPresupuestos = mp.Listar();
 dataGridView1.DataSource =listaPresupuestos;
```

Algun consejo?

Comment: Cuál línea de código tira el error?

Comment: No me manda a una línea..simplemente muestra ese cuadro de dialogo

Comment: Entonces, si ninguna de las líneas que incluyes en tu pregunta lanza un error/excepción, entonces no las necesitamos, correcto? Primero hay que identificar el error. Establece un punto de interrupción en tu programa y sígue la ejecución paso a paso para identificar la línea **exacta** que lanza el error. Una vez que lo sepas, actualiza la pregunta con los detalles necesarios.

Answer (score 0):

Parece que al actualizar la lista ya no lo encuentra por eso aparece error, para cargar el datagv puedes utilizar esto:

```
listaPresupuestos = mp.Listar();
dataGridView1.DataSource=null; 
dataGridView1.DataSource =listaPresupuestos;
```

Espero te pueda servir.

Saludos.